# Do universities have a comprehensive reference document for all their policies and regulations?

Tags: university, policy, disciplinary-action

As an organization, a university has various types of regulations (academics, disciplinary, etc), which are separately documented.

Do (at least) large universities prepare a comprehensive book containing the code of laws of the university in different sections. I mean a reference book addressing all regulations of the university.

For example, when there is an official conflict between two parties, using that reference to justify their actions, instead of dealing with section documents.

If yes, could you please reference them for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will be called a "Policy and Procedures Handbook" or something like that at most universities in the US. The reason to have such a handbook is to ensure that employees follow proper protocols about a range of different issues. This protects both the employees and the universities legally.

Comment: Note that most large employers have reference documents of this sort. Note. however, that it isn't always easy for a non-manager to get access to those books, since some of the policies are often considered confidential.

Answer (score 0):

Some don't, or rather - some have these in multiple documents, with some of the documents not easily accessible to students or junior / adjucnt faculty. That's what it was like in my Alma Mater anyway - and it's a 90 year old university with ~10k undergrads, 2.5k M.Sc. candidates and 700 Ph.D. candidates.